# How can I make Atlas search look for a keyword only once?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

Let's say I have 2 documents in my **MongoDB database**:

Document 1:

```
title: "elephant is an elephant"
description: "this elephant is an elephant"
```

Document 2:

```
title: "duck"
description: "duck is not an elephant"
```

How can I make Atlas search give both these results the **same search score for "elephant"**? I want it to only **look for a keyword once** and not weight the result higher if the keyword appears more often.

Note: Matches of **different** words should still rank higher than matching a single word.
When the user searches for “duck elephant”, document 2 should be listed higher because it matches both words.

Comment: Might not be exactly what you need but the most straight forward way is using constant score modifier. see docs:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/scoring/#constant

Comment: @Oren The problem with this is that I still want to score results higher that contain **different** words from the search query. With this approach the score will be fixed, no matter how many words match (if I understand it correctly)

Comment: Your understanding is correct, try to use the `indexOption: docs` in your index definition with regards to the `title` and/or `description` field. The docs say this:
> The frequency and position of the indexed term are ignored. Only a single occurence of the term is reflected in the score.
docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/define-field-mappings/#string

Comment: @Oren That sounds exactly like what I need. I will try it out and report back!

Comment: @Oren This will still rank results higher where the term appears in multiple different fields, right? I want to count it only once throughout the whole document.

Comment: @Oren I think I can go with your initial idea of using a constant value, but add a separate entry for each word in the search query dynamically. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a **constant score** is that I want to score results higher if **multiple search terms** fit, while only weighting each **individual term** **exactly once**.

I achieved my desired outcome by dynamically adding entries to the search compound operator for each search term, each having a constant search score.

Here is the code (simplified). `searchTerms` is my input query turned into a string array.

```
const shouldQueries = searchTerms.map(searchTerm: string) => ({
    wildcard: {
        query: searchTerm,
        path: ['title', 'description'],
        allowAnalyzedField: true,
        score: { constant: { value: 1 } }
    }
}));

let aggregation = Resource.aggregate()
    .search({
        compound: {
            must: [...],
            should: [...shouldQueries]
        }
    })
```

This should now weight each search term **exactly once**, no matter if it's found in the **title** or the **description**.